# How do I branch arrows using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am drawing a diagram with nodes and arrows using *Tikz*, but do not have an idea how I can make an **arrow branch into two**.

I am using something very similar to this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum
    width=2em]
  {
     F_t(x) & F(x) \\
     A_t & A \\};
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge node [left] {$\mathcal{B}_X$} (m-2-1)
        edge [double] node [below] {$\mathcal{B}_t$} (m-1-2)
    (m-2-1.east|-m-2-2) edge node [below] {$\mathcal{B}_T$}
            node [above] {$\exists$} (m-2-2)
    (m-1-2) edge node [right] {$\mathcal{B}_T$} (m-2-2)
            edge [dashed,-] (m-2-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[Code reference](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/commutative-diagram-tikz/)

Comment: Welcome! What should it look like exactly? What is meant to branch? Every `edge` gets its own arrow tip, because that's how `edge`s work. You can use regular path construction commands between nodes if you just want a tip at the end, say.

Comment: Do you mean something like the effect of `\draw [->] (0,0) to[bend left] (-1,-2); \draw [->] (0,0) to[bend right] (1,-2);`?

Answer (score 1):

My friend, I warmly suggest you the usage of `tikzcd` package. It truly makes life easier. You can find an exhaustive documentation [here](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf). And now onto the code. You'll see It's much shorter than the average painful `tikz` source:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
F_t(x) \arrow[d, "\mathcal{B}_X"'] \arrow[r, "\mathcal{B}_t"', rightharpoondown, shift right=0.25ex] \arrow[r, rightharpoonup, shift left=0.25ex] & F(x) \arrow[d, "\mathcal{B}_T"] \\
A_t \arrow[ru, dashrightarrow, dash] \arrow[r, "\exists", "\mathcal{B}_T"'] & A
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if you perhaps want two normal arrows pointing in the same direction:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
F_t(x) \arrow[d, "\mathcal{B}_X"'] \arrow[r, "\mathcal{B}_t"', shift right=0.65ex] \arrow[r, shift left=0.65ex] & F(x) \arrow[d, "\mathcal{B}_T"] \\
A_t \arrow[ru, dashrightarrow, dash] \arrow[r, "\exists", "\mathcal{B}_T"'] & A
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd be impolite if I didn't answer your question *specifically*. Perhaps you are very skilled in `tikz` and don't feel like jumping onto another package. I understand. Though I have to warn you that `path` is not the best way to go about. In fact (for commutative diagrams) it's pretty horrible. I rewrote the whole diagram because I wasn't able to find a solution in `path` environment. It kind of castrates a wide portion of functions `tikz` has to offer, like for example `xshift` and `yshift` I used to move the arrows. Here's a solution in plain `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.3cm, auto]
\node (A) {$F_t(x)$};
\node(B) [right of=A] {$F(x)$};
\node (C) [below of=A] {$A_t$};
\node (D) [right of=C] {$A$};
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=0.5ex},->] (A) -- (B);
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=-0.5ex},->](A) to node [below] {$\mathcal{B}_{t}$} (B); 
\draw[->](A) to node [left] {$\mathcal{B}_{X}$}(C);
\draw[->](B) to node {$\mathcal{B}_{T}$}(D);
\draw[->](C) to node [below] {$\mathcal{B}_{T}$}(D);
\draw[](C) to node [above] {$\exists$}(D);
\draw[dashed](B) to (C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I hope this post was helpful to you. I wish you a good day.